# Android- How to create 4 square buttons in one row with icons on top of them?

Tags: android, button, tiles

Im trying to create an app which will have 4 square buttons in one row with an icon on top of these buttons. Which is the best way to approach this? I'm trying to do something like this as shown in the image

[image]

Thank You

Comment: there is no best way. What have you tried so far? What exactly is a problem? making buttons square? placing them in a row? placing icons on top of them?

Comment: My 2 cents throw-in: A GridView with a single row of ImageButtons.

Comment: You can use Weight to Divide row equally for 4 of them.Can you post your Code.What have you Done So far??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your drawable image on place of **@mipmap/ic_launcher_round**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="4sp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4">


        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you Tried Table Layout? Although you can use any Layout, I suggest you stick to one Parent layout like the relative layout and then multiple child layouts to manage to UI elements.

Comment: I'd recommend not to use "children layouts" at all, since nesting layouts is bad for performances.

Comment: True. But sometimes when you don't want to use Constraint Layout, you have to use such methods.

Comment: Or you could use a GridView, as I suggested in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solutions everyone. The image i posted was edited on photoshop. Now I did it in android studio using linear layout

[image]